# My mapview hides a lot of annotation points, how do i force ALL points to show?

Tags: swift, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview, mkpointannotation

I have 200+ points on my map and they a lot of them are hidden upon runtime until zoom in is increased. Is there a boolean function or other to resolve this?

Comment: I don't think this is possible as it is an added feature to prevent annotations overlapping. More info here: https://medium.com/@hashemi.eng1985/map-view-does-not-show-all-annotations-at-first-9789d77f6a3a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create your annotation view class outside of your view controller and change it’s displayPriority = .required

```
class annotationView: MKMarkerAnnotationView {

  override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
    willSet {
        
      guard let "arrayOfAnnotations" = "newValue" as? "annotationClass" else {
        return
      }
        self.displayPriority = .required
      }
    }
}
```